# How do $\ln$ and $e$ cancel out when there is an exponent that is negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question about $\ln$ and $e$.

Essentially I know that $e$ and $\ln$ cancel/reverse each other to give $x$. Ex: $e^{\ln x}  = x$

But how does this work: $-e^{-\ln 2} = -1/2$

I thought it would just give me $-(-2)$.

Comment: But doesn't the E and LN cancel out so the 2 comes down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that  that $a^{-b}= (a^b)^{-1}$.

Thus $e^{-\ln 2}= (e^{\ln 2})^{-1}= 2^{-1}= 1/2$.

Comment: So am I right in saying e^ln 2 cancels to just give the 2. So if I had ln 2^e I would also just ignore the E and LN and just get the 2?

Comment: Also is it okay to always take the power out like you did as long as I put it back in?

Comment: No, $(\ln 2)^e$ is not $2$ neither is $\ln (2^e)$. only $e^{\ln 2}=2$ and $\ln (e^2)= 2$.  Not every occurences of $e$ can be "cancelled" with a $\ln$. Yes you can always take a power out in the sense that $a^{bc}= (a^{c})^b$ is a general rule for calculating with exponential expressions.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $e^{\ln x} = x$ and $p \ln x = ln x^p$.

Using this we get

$$
-e^{-\ln 2} = -e^{-1\ln 2}= -e^{\ln 2^{-1}} = -e^{ln(\frac{1}{2})}= -\frac{1}{2}.
$$